# Which end is up when planting a mango seed?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, germination

I have a seed that has already germinated. I've had it in water for a day and it has already grown some in the water.  One end has a slight purple color to it, the other one is long and white.

Which end should be pointing up when I bury it in the potting soil in a container?

Comment: What area/climate are you in?

Comment: Hi James, can you please improve your question so that it can be easily understood. What is a/c? What do you mean by "one and the other has a color to it"?

Comment: A picture would be awesome.

Answer (score 9):

The end of your seed with a lighter area on top is called the eye, place the seed with its eye facing up.  Cover the seed with half an inch (1.27 centimeters) of soil. The seed should sprout within a few weeks.  Water your plant with lukewarm water whenever you see the soil is a bit dry. 
**Mangos don't need a lot of water.**