# Can I plant this mango seed

Tags: seeds, planting

Today preparing a mango for breakfast, I retrieved the mango seed. The mango somehow just split in the middle and the inner seed was free. That never happened before. I am now wondering, whether I could plant this seed. It looks somehow damaged.

How do I plant it, which side goes up. How deep do I plant it,  and what else do I need to consider?

[image: Mango Seed Photo]

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8355/which-end-is-up-when-planting-a-mango-seed

Comment: @NiallC. Partially I think. I also asked about the health state of that seed.

Answer (score 6):

So here is what I did. I laid the seed horizontally in a small pot. About the same amount of soil above and below. And kept the soil moist. After about two weeks a root was visible under the pot.[image]
After another week or so, the plant catapulted it self out of the soil with already 4 leafs. I re potted the mango and saw, that it came out of the non pointy end of the seed. About 5-6 weeks later it looks like this:

[image]

Initially it had the leafs hanging. But it starts no to raise them. So I think everything is OK with the mango.

Comment: I'm at this stage, with just a bit more growth than you. (I'm sure this has grown since then) Could you give an update so we can see?

Comment: @Throsby Actually my plant is in no good condition right now. See this new question of mine: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14086/what-is-wrong-with-my-mango-plant

Comment: Oh no! That terrifying! I'm so sorry!

Answer (score 3):

I would just throw it in a pot with 2 to 3 inches of potting soil, with the pointy end up, to see if it grows. It either will or it won't, but at least you've given it a chance.