# What is wrong with my Mango plant?

Tags: diseases, cuttings

[I planted a mango seed this spring.](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9413/can-i-plant-this-mango-seed) And it went good. But growth stagnated after a while and totally stopped. Then I noticed some bulgy excrescence on the top, with a very dark almost black color. I did nothing there, just left it on my balcony. Recently I noticed that its leafs started to get brown. Two already fell to the ground.

I took it into the living room, onto the window bank. I thought maybe it was too could outside. So now there are 3 new shoots. Two at the very bottom of the stem. And one a little bit under the first leafs.

I include two photos to show these. But how do I proceed? I definitely don't want separate stems growing, so should I cut those new ones? And what about the shoot at the top? should I keep it, cut the rest of the plant off?

By the way, you can still see the mango seed looking out of the soil.

[image: mango bottom]

[image: mango top]

Comment: I agree with Bamboo...cut just above and at an angle away from that top shoot.  I'd also repot this plant in good potting soil after washing out the pot. Soak the plant then allow to dry out before watering again! Are you using tap water?  Also shows lots of white crusting from salts in tap water.  Use bottled distilled water.  Make sure if you have a saucer that you don't leave water sitting beneath this pot.  No rocks in the bottom of pot, either...

Comment: What happened to your mango?

Comment: Sadly, it died.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some kind of fungal infection - cut the main stem back down to where that new shoot is on the right (in the picture), at an angle away from the shoot, in hopes the trouble does not spread down the plant and kill it. Leave the new ones at the bottom until you see how the plant fares once cut back.

Comment: I'll keep you up to date on how it went.